# How to adjust the vertical placement of markups in Lilypond

Tags: lilypond, engraving

Using Lilypond 2.20 on Ubuntu 20.04.

This code:

```
...
%% fingering symbols
fngaLong = \finger\markup{\box{\pad-markup #0.2 \override #'(font-name . "pipa") \fontsize #7 "a-"}}
...
\appoggiatura{c8-3} a2-1\trill\fngaLong
...
```

renders like this:
[image]

But I must place the trill *under* the boxed fingering symbol. In another word, I must swap the vertical position of the trill symbol and the boxed fingering symbol. How to do this?

Another question: The finger number 3 is smaller than the finger number 1. I'd like to make the 3 as big as the 1. How to do this?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The order in which several things are stacked vertically is controlled by the `outside-staff-priority`. The lower the priority, the closer to the staff. You can find all the info in the [in the corresponding section of the docs](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.19/Documentation/learning/outside_002dstaff-objects.en.html#the-outside_002dstaff_002dpriority-property).

As for the fingering, the easiest way would probably be using a tweak (at least if you want to do this in one place only). Instead of something like `c8-3`, you would write `c8-\tweak font-size #2 -3`. If you would like to do this globally for all the grace notes, then, sadly, I don't know how to do that. Maybe you could manipulate the [`Grace_engraver`](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.20/Documentation/internals/grace_005fengraver) in your `\layout` block somehow, but I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 5):

I read the answer from @Ramillies, the document is comprehensive but I did not figure out how to use the commands correctly. Then I found a very simple example in the doc page [Expressive marks attached to notes](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.20/Documentation/notation/expressive-marks-attached-to-notes).

Now this vertical stack of markups is exactly what I want:

[image]

My source code:

```
...
%% fingering symbols
fngaLong = \finger\markup{\box{\pad-markup #0.2 \override #'(font-name . "pipa") \fontsize #7 "a-"}}
...
\once \override TrillSpanner.script-priority = #-300
\appoggiatura{c8-3\startTrillSpan^\fngaLong} a2-1
c8\stopTrillSpan d4\fermata c8
```